# how can i know what is the format code of parameter that comes to my page?

Tags: unicode, asp-classic

how can i know what is the format code of parameter that comes to my page?

whorking with ASP

some of the character that i see cant found in the DB (access)

i want to know the unicode of the value

Comment: in search with English LETTERS its working but in other unicode(HEBREW windows-1255) not working [the values on DB save in windows-1255 code)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using C#, you can get the 16-bit characters of strings as integers using `(int) foo[0]`.

(In VB.NET, I think it would be `Convert.ToInt32(foo.Chars(0))`. In VBA, `Asc(foo)`.)

If the string you're passing to ADO is correct, but the results are not as expected, either the data in the database was already corrupted by some earlier non-Unicode-friendly process, or else Access is not treating the input string and the database record as equal for some unexpected reason. ([Equivalence of Unicode strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) is a bit complicated.)